# Pasar texto de un select a un input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

Estoy tratando de que al seleccionar un valor de un select, al abrir un modal, el value y el texto del select se pasen a distintos inputs. Que serian los siguientes:

rut_usu = a este input se le pasa el value de la opción seleccionada.

jc = a este input se le pasa el texto de la opción seleccionada.

EL value se pasa correctamente al input rut_usu, pero no así el texto a jc, este me dice "undefined". Los valores de mi select los estoy trayendo de mis base de datos.

Puse un alert y me arroja todo el texto del select

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Function del model que muestra los datos del select

```
 public function get_usuarios() {

  $this->db->select('rut_usu as rut, pnombre as nom,apellido_pa as pat, apellido_ma as mat');
  $this->db->from('usuarios');
  $this->db->where('id_tip=2');
  $this->db->order_by('pnombre', 'asc');
  $usuarios = $this->db->get();

  if($usuarios->num_rows() > 0 ){

  return $usuarios->result();

    }
  }
```

El select que se muestra en la vista

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Jefes de Carrera</label>
      <?= form_open(base_url().'mCalendar/get_usuarios'); ?>
       <select class="form-control" id="rut_jc" name="rut_jc">
         <option>--Seleccione un Jefe de Carrera--</option>
         <?php 
                 $this->load->model('mCalendar');
                 $usuarios = $this->mCalendar->get_usuarios();

                 foreach($usuarios as $fila){

                 echo '<option value="'. $fila->rut.'">'. $fila->nom .' '. $fila->pat .' '.$fila->mat.'</option>';

           }
            ?>

       </select>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Javascript

```
  $("#rut_jc").change(function(){

  var op=document.getElementById("rut_jc");
  var tt=document.getElementById("rut_usu"); 
  var jc=document.getElementById("jc");

  //alert($("#rut_jc").text()); 

  if (op.selectedIndex > 0)tt.value= op.value ; 
  if (op.selectedIndex > 0)jc.value= op.text ; 

  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen dia Kvothe_0077

Usando el JQuery para obtener y poner los valores.
intenta con:

```
  $("#rut_jc").change(function(){

  var op=document.getElementById("rut_jc");

  if (op.selectedIndex > 0)$("#rut_usu").val("#rut_jc".val());
  if (op.selectedIndex > 0)$("#jc").val($( "#rut_jc option:selected" ).text()) ; 


  });
```

Saludos

Comment: Te agradezco por responder, sin embargo, no pasa ningún valor a alguno de los inputs.

Comment: Si quito if (op.selectedIndex > 0)$("#rut_usu").val("#rut_jc".val()); se muestra el texto del select

Comment: En ve de eso agregue var tt=document.getElementById("rut_usu");  y if (op.selectedIndex > 0)tt.value= op.value ;  Muchas gracias

Comment: Su respuesta es incorrecta en la parte de seleccionar el id `rut_jc` debería ser `$("#rut_usu").val($("#rut_jc").val());`

Comment: Si, eso es mejor, son menos lineas de código, muchas gracias

Answer (score -1):

En el header poner:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#usuario").change(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            $("#asunto").val(value);
        });
    });
</script>
```

El select a pasar el valor

```
 <select name="usuario" id="usuario">
    <option value="0">Selección:</option>
    <?php            
    $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT * FROM listadocolaboradores");            
    while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {          
        echo '<option value="'.$valores["nombre"].'">'.$valores["nombre"].'</option>';           
    }
    ?>
    </select><br/>
```

El input a llegar el valor:

```
<label>Asunto</label>
<input type="text" name="subject2" id="asunto"/><br/>
```

Tener en cuenta solo los `id` de cada elmento, el `select` y el `input`...